# Regex lookbehind - excluding words from searches

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to search my corpus for words such as *game* or *shame* but I would like to specify the search to exclude three strings *a game*/*a shame* or , *A game*/*A shame* and *a/an/A/An WORD game* or  *a/an/A/An WORD shame* , where WORD is a modifier, e.g., *a great game* or *a great shame*.

If someone could help me out, that would be great, thanks!

In my corpus, the optional WORD between the indefinite article *a/an* and *game* or *a/an* and *shame* is most commonly *great* and *real*. So even excluding these two, would already help me a lot.

The lookbehind below works perfectly to exclude *a/A*

```
(?<!a\s|A\s)\bshame\b
```

To exclude the modifying WORD, I was trying to use ?\w in the lookbehind grep, but it just wouldn't work - the grep below without *?* runs and it still excludes examples such as *a shame*, but it still returns the undesired examples such as *a great shame* or *a crying shame* - see concordance lines (3) and (4) in the sample text below:

```
    (?<!a\s|A\s|a\b\w\b|A\b\w\b)\bshame\b
```

The tool I'm using to implement regex is AntConc, which supports Perl regular expressions.

Sample text with two irrelevant examples (3 & 4) after using the search string below

```
(?<!a\s|A\s)\bshame\b
```

---

1 (match shame)

> , people ogling from the sidelines.&nbsp; If you want a closer look, you have to ring for entry and wait to be admitted.&nbsp; I guess me and Saul just have no shame (or just know the benefits of our bank accounts being in hard currencies), because we wandered into plenty.&nbsp; Lots and lots of little boutiques and edgily designed fashion stores with music blaring.&  abbutterflie.txt    47  1

2 (match shame)

> last twenty years and I've experienced all sorts of biggotry but I seriously thought that anti black nazism in football wass a thing of the past. You should all hang your heads in shame, bunch of [badword]s.       adamdphillips.txt   57  1

3 (don't match shame)

> me monetarily as I wasn't that close to her, but she was really good friends with the other girl and it's messed that up for them a bit, which is a great shame. Anyway, Holly and I have since found somewhere to move in just the two of us. It's going to cost an absolute fortune and I'm going to be eating basics beans on   aderyn.txt  60  1

4 (don't match shame)

> are loads of amazingly good bands out there, gigging up and down the country who will never get signed because no-one can figure out how to market them, and this is a crying  shame. There are artists out there like <a href="http://www.angelsintheabattoir.com/" rel="nofollow">Thea Gilmore</a> and <a href="http://blog.amandapalmer.net/" rel="nofollow"> Amanda Palmer&  aderyn.txt  60  2

5 (match shame)

> /><br />"There is no better time to show these terrorists that we have no fear of them. Instead we are forced, through the cowardly acts of our superiors, to hide in shame."<br /><br />But Herb Wiseman, high school consultant for Lee County, Florida, pointed to the July 7 London bombings.<br /><br />"What happens if kids get on     aggy91.txt  64  1

Comment: Do you have a list of these WORDs? Because there is no such thing as "excluding an adjective". And could you please post a short example with expected outcome?

Comment: @colburton There could be, if you compiled a hard-coded list of every adjective :p

Comment: What language is this for? Depending on the language, variable length look behinds may or may not be supported.

Comment: It's a nice phd thesis. The regex is extremely simply, unfortunately I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get data for my study - put simply, I would like to get exclusively mass-noun uses of the word *game*. I'm a corpus linguist. I would like to be able to avoid as much noise as possible in my data. Therefore, if possible, I would like to exclude uses of *game* as a count noun, i.e., those preceded by the indefinite article *a* and possibly by *a/an + another word*, i.e., modifier.

Comment: This question will greatly improve with some context.  I have whacked together a bit of [sample text](https://regex101.com/r/H8iCeg/1).  Please consider adding it or something similar to your question, and express exactly which words you wish to match and why.  If you have additional sentences that will expose unique word patterns, please extend the sample text.  Volunteers will need to know the regex limitations of AntConc -- so describing the rules on things like "lookaround" and such will be helpful, but perhaps a link to the rules would be easier.

Comment: To avoid troubling volunteers with repeated answer edits, it is important that you fully explain the rules of the pattern to be created.  Are you looking for all articles?  `a`, `an`, `any` etc.  How about verb conjugation/tense?  Please be very clear.  After you have generated a clear and fully considered question, we can see what else needs to happen to attract high quality responses.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you! i will try and make my query more specific. Briefly speaking, I would only like to exclude noise in the form of a+\bgame\b and a/an+WORD+\bgame\b. I've been trying to find some rules on using regex with AntConc, but the only information I found was that AntConc supports Perl regular expressions.

Comment: Please include (in your question via edit) a generous block of sample text that will illustrate all of the possible challenges in capturing the desired substring.  Also, include your expected result given the block of text.  This will reinforce what you are trying to explain in your question.  There is a good question in here, I'm just trying to help you to express it clearly / fully.

Comment: Thanks again! I've included a sample text that I'm currently working on and modified my query accordingly. If someone could help me out, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because variable length negative lookbehinds are not allowed, the approach in your previous question's answer won't transfer to this one.

I've gone with a `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` pattern.  This will match and discard the disqualified matches, and only retain qualifying matches:

`/[Aa]n?( \w+)? shame(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|shame/` 3844 steps ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8iCeg/5))

Or if you wish to include word boundary metacharacters:

`/\b[Aa]n?( \w+)? shame\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bshame\b/` 4762 steps ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8iCeg/4))

Comment: Thanks a million!!! it works perfectly! I jst added the bit at the beginning to make sure it also skips *a/A shame" :) \b[Aa] shame\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[Aa]n? \w+ shame(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bshame\b

Comment: @Karolina Wait what?  are you worried with the `n?`?  The `?` makes the `n` optional, you shouldn't need to create a third "alternative" in the pattern.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: hmmm, i only added the third alternative, cos without it, i was still getting examples like *a shame*, but i was not getting any occurrences of the kind *a great / real shame*

Comment: Oh right, use this: `\b[Aa]n?( \w+)? shame\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bshame\b`  It will make the middle word optional.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8iCeg/4)